# I want to print my answer to the console

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to programming.  I'm following the tutorials on codeacademy.com and I'm stuck on a couple of tutorials.  It's giving me trouble with console.log()

The first one is a simple function calculating the cost of 5 oranges at $5 each.

```
var orangeCost = function(price){
    var cost = price * 5;  //the 5 is the number of oranges

};

orangeCost(5);
```

and the tutorial says this is correct.  However, I want to return the answer to the console and when I try to do

```
console.log(orangeCost(5));
```

I get an error saying  "TypeError: string is not a function".

Another one that is giving me the same error is

```
var my_number = 7; //this has global scope

var timesTwo = function(number) {
    var my_number = number * 2;
console.log("Inside the function my_number is: ");
console.log(my_number);
}; 

timesTwo(7);

console.log("Outside the function my_number is: ");
console.log(my_number);
```

Answer (score 2):

simply do this -

```
return cost;
```

inside your `orangecost` -

```
var orangeCost = function(price){
    var cost = price * 5;  //the 5 is the number of oranges
    return cost;
};

console.log(orangeCost(5));
```

Comment: Thanks. As for the second code.. Same thing? The whole code was already written in the tutorial except I had to add the    var inside the function.

Comment: @user3873131: Er, could you tell me what errors you are getting for the second case? For me it works just fine: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/642Eh/).

Comment: Well in the console for codeacademy it says the same TypeError.  But when I went to jsfiddle, I see that it works just fine.  So it must be a bug on the tutorial's side.  Thanks for your help!  Being brand new to programming I was nervous posting on here.

Comment: It turns out that I just had to refresh the page and now all the code is working just fine.  Don't know what it was, but everything is great.  Glad to know my scripts were written correctly.  Again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error you are saying `"TypeError: string is not a function"` occurs when you do something like bellow

```
console.log("orangeCost"(5));// so here "orangeCost" is a string you cann't use that as function.
```

And you have to do a return from your function.

```
var orangeCost = function(price){
    var cost = price * 5;  //the 5 is the number of oranges
    return cost
};
```